# How to move data records from a table to another with same fields?

Tags: servicenow

I have a question about moving data record from a table to another with the same fields available.

I have found some solutions that require scripting, is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this myself, but if the columns have the same name, xml or xlsx export and import should work (for the xml you'll probably need to edit it and change the table name).

I'd recommend testing on a non-productive instance first (a developer instance if you do not have any other at hand), and if the target table already has data in it, you should probably do a backup before (xml export is my preferred backup option)